# how a pointer accesss a data member of structure

Tags: c, data-structures

I am making a doubly link list and  I used `temp->next->prev` for accessing the previous address of the next node and when I wrote `*((*temp).next).prev` instead of the previous syntax it didn't work .can anyone please explain the mistake and the reason of the mistake ?

Comment: `temp->next->prev1` == `(*(*temp).next).prev`

Comment: Why would you write `temp->next->prev` instead of `temp` though?

Comment: @Lundin possibly to check if the links are correct. `temp->next->prev == temp`

Comment: @KamiKaze If `temp->next->prev` is incorrect, why would `temp->next` be any better? Though I suppose could like this might rather make sense during insertion of a new node in a linked list.

Answer (score 4):

The field selector ".", which is a postfix operator, has higher precedence than pointer dereference "*", which is a prefix operator, so the expression should be `(*(*temp).next).prev`.